# Moving from Neo4j Community to Enterprise

Tags: neo4j

I'm preparing to convert a Neo4j community instance into an HA setup on Neo4j Enterprise.

I'm curious on how to move all of the data over from the community instance and ensure it's duplicated on all of the new instances before aiming my production application at it.

My assumption is, I will stop the Neo4j community instance, copy over the graph.db folder to all three of the new instances, do the relevant configurations for HA, and then I can start them up and they should stay synced from there.  Does this sound right, or should I just put graph.db on one of the new instances (master) and let Neo4j do the propagation?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both approaches are possible, so either copy community's `graph.db` to one enterprise instance and be sure to start up that one first. The other instances will then receive a full copy via the cluster data synchronization process.

If you copy the `graph.db` to all three enterprise instances you can safely start them in arbitrary order. No sync is required - so this one might be faster.